# Get data from database in adapter, good or bad?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a situation that I must get some data from the database with a button click in Recyclerview item and fill the Recyclerview adapter again with new data.
Should I put the database fetch code in button onClickListener in the adapter or it is better to do it in another way? For example with help of Callback in activity.

Comment: It is better to decouple your database calling code from your UI event code

Comment: @KenWolf So what is the best option for this situation? A callback to activity then fetch and refill the adapter from activity?

Comment: There are many different ways to do this and it is hard to recommend something without knowing anything about your application.

Comment: @KenWolf There is a button in one of the rows of the recyclerview that with clicking on it, some data must be fetched from DB and fill the adapter list again. I can do this in the adapter itself(in button onClickListener) or using a callback in activity. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

It is a definitely bad scenario, because database belongs to model and RecyclerView - to View layers. All presentation logic will be in adapter (along with execution in background). It will lead to difficult to maintain application.

Comment: What about using callback pattern and do this work in the activity then refilling the adapter list?